# How to get bitmap from a url in android?

Tags: android

I have a uri like which has an image

```
file:///mnt/...............
```

How to use this uri to get the image but it returns null, please tell me where i am wrong.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.toString());
```

Comment: My perfect solution: `val imageBitmap = Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).get()`

Answer (score 166, accepted):

This is a simple one line way to do it:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://....");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: That isn't a one-liner as creating your url object should be surrounded in try-catch.

Comment: The idea was a one line way to get the bitmap given you had already defined an url.

Comment: `url.openConnection().getInputStream()` can be replaced with simply `url.openStream()`

Comment: this throw android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Must be a new android feature (and a good one at that), you might temporarily try targeting a lower android version, or alternatively putting this one liner in a separate thread.

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 don't call any network operation on main thread, use asynctask or thread instead

Comment: url.openStream() is also not working Please update this code

Comment: @brthornbury This will lead to app crashing, do you have any idea for the moment ?

Comment: For the App crash: Instead of "IOException e" use: "Exception e"

Answer (score 23):

This should do the trick:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
} // Author: silentnuke
```

Don't forget to add the internet permission in your manifest.

Comment: how bout my url has https connection?

Comment: @LukeTaylor This doesn't work anymore it will leads to crash at the app.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so you are trying to get a bitmap from a file? Title says URL. Anyways, when you are getting files from external storage in Android you should never use a direct path. Instead call getExternalStorageDirectory() like so:

```
File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + PATH_TO_IMAGE);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapFile);
```

getExternalStorageDirectory() gives you the path to the SD card.
Also you need to declare the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the Manifest.