# How to Convert Image url into Drawable Int

Tags: android, json

Good Morning All !!!!

I am trying to display images in Imageview. But My requirement is ,i need to display images in Drawable Integer Format.I am getting data from Server and getting image in url format..

```
For ex :http://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg
```

I want to convert this image in Drawable Format.

**This is My code**

This is my Interface

```
 public interface ECCardData<T> {

    @DrawableRes
    Integer getMainBackgroundResource();

    @DrawableRes
    Integer getHeadBackgroundResource();

    List<T> getListItems();
}
```

**My Getter and Setter**

```
     private Integer headBackgroundResource;

public Integer getHeadBackgroundResource() {
        return headBackgroundResource;
    }

    public void setHeadBackgroundResource(Integer headBackgroundResource) {
        this.headBackgroundResource = headBackgroundResource;
    }
```

**This  code  where i set images**

```
Integer drawableRes = dataset.get(position).getHeadBackgroundResource();
    if (drawableRes != null) {
        headView.setHeadImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(pagerContainer.getResources(), drawableRes, new BitmapFactoryOptions()));
    }
```

**This is my parsing**

```
 public static ArrayList<CardData> ParseCraft(String response) throws JSONException {


        ArrayList<CardData> alUser = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("products");

        for (int j = 0; j < parentArray.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);

            CardData user = new CardData();

            user.setHeadTitle(finalObject.getString("product"));
            user.setPersonName(finalObject.getString("product_code"));

            JSONObject productJsonObject = finalObject.getJSONObject("main_pair");
            JSONObject productJsonObject1 = productJsonObject.getJSONObject("detailed");

            user.setHeadBackgroundResource(productJsonObject1.getString("image_path"));



            alUser.add(user);
        }

        return alUser;
    }
```

**My json response**

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "product_id": "863",
        "product": "LAVA 4G CONNECT M1",
        "company_name": "SAPTHAGIRI MOBILES",
        "age_verification": "N",
        "age_limit": "0",
        "product_code": "SGMM00044",
        "product_type": "P",
        "status": "A",
        "company_id": "34",
        "approved": "Y",
        "list_price": "0.00",
        "amount": "2",
        "weight": "0.000",
        "length": "0",
        "width": "0",
        "height": "0",
        "shipping_freight": "0.00",
        "low_avail_limit": "0",
        "timestamp": "1492758588",
        "updated_timestamp": "1500273558",
        "usergroup_ids": "0",
        "is_edp": "N",
        "edp_shipping": "N",
        "unlimited_download": "N",
        "tracking": "B",
        "free_shipping": "N",
        "zero_price_action": "R",
        "is_pbp": "N",
        "is_op": "N",
        "is_oper": "N",
        "is_returnable": "Y",
        "return_period": "10",
        "avail_since": "0",
        "out_of_stock_actions": "N",
        "localization": "",
        "min_qty": "0",
        "max_qty": "0",
        "qty_step": "0",
        "list_qty_count": "0",
        "tax_ids": "",
        "options_type": "P",
        "exceptions_type": "F",
        "details_layout": "default",
        "shipping_params": "a:5:{s:16:\"min_items_in_box\";i:0;s:16:\"max_items_in_box\";i:0;s:10:\"box_length\";i:0;s:9:\"box_width\";i:0;s:10:\"box_height\";i:0;}",
        "facebook_obj_type": "activity",
        "buy_now_url": "",
        "cod": "N",
        "price": "3094.000000",
        "category_ids": [
            295
        ],
        "position": "0",
        "seo_name": "lava-4g-connect-m1",
        "seo_path": "166/234/295",
        "average_rating": null,
        "discussion_type": "D",
        "discussion_thread_id": "619",
        "main_category": 295,
        "main_pair": {
            "pair_id": "2577",
            "image_id": "0",
            "detailed_id": "3266",
            "position": "0",
            "detailed": {
                "object_id": "863",
                "object_type": "product",
                "image_path": "http://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg",
                "alt": "",
                "image_x": "635",
                "image_y": "476",
                "http_image_path": "http://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg",
                "https_image_path": "https://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg",
                "absolute_path": "/home/mymartmycart/public_html/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg",
                "relative_path": "detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg"
            }
        },
        "base_price": "3094.000000",
        "selected_options": [],
        "has_options": false,
        "product_options": [],
        "discounts": {
            "A": 0,
            "P": 0
        },
        "product_features": [],
        "qty_content": []
    }
```

Comment: this might be some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url

Comment: @harshaldeshmukh if you just wanted to show the image coming from server url inside your imageview you can use  glide or picaso library to display it directly to imageview

Comment: @harshal you can also convert your url into bitmap and set the bitmap to your imageview here is a link to convert url to bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831188/how-to-get-bitmap-from-a-url-in-android

Comment: ok. let me try this one

Comment: But when static images i set it display with above code?@ Snehal Gongle Now, I have to display server images .Please Check my interface code above

Comment: `R.drawable.something` is a resource ID created during compilation time and you cannot  "add" / "convert" the downloaded image into `R.drawable`, your interface design is wrong - you should use `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` concept instead

Comment: @HarshalDeshmukh look you have to remove your this code and place glide code  user.setHeadBackgroundResource(productJsonObject1.getString("image_path"));   Glide.with(context)
     .load(url)
   .into(imageView);

Comment: why you want this if you want to set the image you can use picasso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This code is working for me to convert Server  image url into Bitmap**

```
 String drawableRes="http://kartpay.biz/api/v1/file/banner/IHMOcSHU7yoTVOkwYi1bOOz8shrXXrJhayCPFO17.jpeg"
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(drawableRes);
            headView.setHeadImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)url.getContent()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can doing this work in background with coroutines :

```
    private fun loadImageFromWebUrl(url: String?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val image  = try {
            val iStream = java.net.URL(url).content as InputStream
            Drawable.createFromStream(iStream, "src name")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }

        image?.let {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                imageView.setImageDrawable = image 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way in 2020 than this?

Answer (score 0):

**i think that is not possible to convert image url i to drawable int**

**you can use lib to show image from url try this**

**1. glide**

you can use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load image from url look the below code it can help you in simple way

compile this library

```
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

than load image like this

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(mainMenuDataModelArrayList.get(position)
     .getIMG()).into(holder.imageView);
```

**2. [use picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)**

compile this library

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

than load image like this

```
Picasso.
  with(context).
  load(url).
  into(imageview);
```

**or try this**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

Comment: I already try Glide and Picasso , its not showing image . I am Using Ramotion Expandable Collection Animation Library. In this, Only Integer image declare as per provided code above. Before here static images set ex.R.Drwable.Image1 .But now i want to set it dynamic

Comment: Which Exception share it

Comment: How to convert String Image_url into resource_id @Nilesh. I tried solution on web but not working? this is my url_image : http://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg        this solution i tried int resID = pagerContainer.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableRes , "drawable",  dataset.get(position).getHeadBackgroundResource()); @ Snehal Gongle please help

Answer (score 0):

You can download image from server URL to your image view by below code

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebURL(String url) {
try {
    InputStream iStream = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(ist, "src name");
    return drawable;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}}
```

you can also use third party library to download image into direct imageView

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Picasso.with(context).load("image web url").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified this library to do that.
https://github.com/upendra-bajpai/expanding-collection-network/
if you are having any difficulty you can file an issue there.
instead of resource data, you can pass URL there.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Can use Picasso library:

add gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.mymartmycart.com/images/detailed/3/4G_CONNECT_M1.jpeg").into(imageView);
```

more info http://square.github.io/picasso/